# how to get element from array of elements and render it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have  array of elements I would like to find an element from array by class and I need to separate the element from array?

```
var mainEl=$(htmlContent);

/*
mainEl:

[el1,el2.classItem,el3#funID]

*/
var needEl;
mainEl.each(function(){
if($(this).hasClass("classItem"))
 needEl=$(this)
});

//render content without needEl
$(".container").append(mainEl);
//render seperatly needEl
$(".separate").append(needEl);
```

But this is not working as Expected,

is there any simple way to do it or am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the problem with this

Comment: try : `mainEl.children().each(function(){`

Comment: the whole content loading in the container but I have to separate the classItem.

Comment: @PSR elements in array

Comment: @Cherniv mainEl is array of elements so I have to filter mainEl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could do this. If I understand you right, this is one good way:

```
var $content = $(htmlContent);
var $separate = $content.filter('.classItem');
var $main = $content.not( $separate );
$(".container").append( $main );
$(".separate").append( $separate );
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straightforward when you use the following helper function:

```
$.fn.others = function() {
    return this.end().not(this);
};
```

It effectively reverses the previous operation. This is how you could use it:

```
$(htmlContent)
    .filter('.classItem') // take .classItem first
      .appendTo('.separate') // and append to separate
    .others() // take the remaining items
      .appendTo('.container'); // and append to main
```

Answer (score 0):

It'd be easier to help you if you described in greater detail what you mean by "not working as Expected". You're not removing `needEl` from the `mainEl` collection, that would be one issue.

You could do something like this:

```
var mainEl = $(htmlContent);
$('.container').append( mainEl.filter(function() { return !$(this).hasClass('classItem');  }) );
$('.separate').append( mainEl.filter(function() { return $(this).hasClass('classItem');  }) );
```

Comment: You know that `filter()` accepts a selector right? `mainEl.filter('.classItem')` for instance :)

Comment: @Jack: Hrrm, I do now! Thanks for the heads up.